# How to unit test guice createinjector method

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking, mockito, guice

I have following main method call where I initialize guice modules using static createInjector method

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(Stage.PRODUCTION, new MyServiceModule());
    MyService component = injector.getInstance(MyService.class);
    component.doSomething();
}
```

Is there any other way of unit testing below code apart from using power-mockito? Do people test main method like this?

Comment: Do you want to mock something? Why?

Comment: what's the business value in unit-testing that ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Guice injector in JUnit tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5633915/guice-injector-in-junit-tests)

Answer (score 3):

I don't unit test this kind of code as it's more cumbersome, obscure and provides very little benefit. If you really want to test this, just call the static `main` method from a test, and you'll need to figure out how to find out if it works as expected (maybe have a `doSomething()` method in the same class as main that delegates to `component`?).

I do test this indirectly as part of my application end-to-end tests, when I fire up the application and poke it with a few tests to ensure everything is glued together nicely.

And please don't use powermock. It's a useful tool, but not the kind to use lightly, and definitely not in *modern* projects.

Comment: precisely right, people are too quick to apply "unit-testing"  to every obscure piece of code they see.