# How to mock an object with Guice @Inject?

Tags: java, mockito, guice

I have a class A and a class B.

```
public class A{
    @Inject // Guice Inject
    private B b;
}
```

The test class looks like -

```
public class ATest{
    private B b;
    
    private A a;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        b = Mockito.mock(b.class);
        a = new A();
    }
}
```

The thing is that class B isn't getting mocked. In the test class, there's a NullPointerException whenever a method of B is getting invoked. I can't make changes to class A. Please help me out on how to mock class B successfully?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that in your case it's not that B isn't mocked, but that it is not injected into `a`.

One way to have it injected would be to create a Guice `Injector` in the test with a `Module`, which would bind a Class to be injected, `B` in your case, to a concrete instance of `B`, and then use `Injector#injectMembers(a)` to have b injected into `a`.

Working example:

```java
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.mockito.Mockito;

import com.google.inject.AbstractModule;
import com.google.inject.Guice;
import com.google.inject.Inject;
import com.google.inject.Injector;

class InjectableTest {
  private static class Service {
    @Inject
    private Object obj;

    public Object getObj() {
      return obj;
    }
  }

  private final Object obj = Mockito.mock(Object.class);
  private final Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(new AbstractModule() {
    @Override
    protected void configure() {
      bind(Object.class).toInstance(obj);
    }
  });

  @Test
  void t() {
    Service s = new Service();
    injector.injectMembers(s);
    Assertions.assertEquals(obj, s.getObj());
  }
}
```

If you need to do it more often than only for one test, have a look at the answers of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5633915/guice-injector-in-junit-tests) question, which discuss different ways of Guice dependency injection in unit tests.